# How to Import webpage with only the data I need?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm new to google sheets and trying to import data from a website to my spreadsheet. The website URL is

https://sagarin.usatoday.com/2023-2/college-basketball-team-ratings-2022-23

I've managed to import some data, but it's not in a format I can use. I want to import the Team name and the 5 power rankings for each team, so I can add the 5 rankings together and come up with a total. When I managed to import the data it includes the team's win lose record in the same cell as the power ranking, which makes it unusable because I can't simply add the power rankings.

Below is the function I'm using to import the data

```
=IMPORTXML("https://sagarin.usatoday.com/2023-2/college-basketball-team-ratings-2022-23/","/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/pre/font/font/font/font")
```

Any idea how I can get just the team names and the 5 separate power rankings associated with each team?

I've tried numerous times with different functions, but the following is the closest I've come to getting what I want. I only wanted the team names and the 5 power rankings associated with each team. What I got was team names and power rankings, but it also included numbers for win loses and other stats in the same cells, which I don't want.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://sagarin.usatoday.com/2023-2/college-basketball-team-ratings-2022-23/","/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/pre/font/font/font/font")
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected value from your URL. Can you provide your expected value?

Comment: Hi, the website contains a ranking for college basketball teams. There are 362 different teams and each have 5 separate rankings. I want to pull the team names and their 5 associated rankings for each team into my google sheet.  I basically want to pull the rankings into my spread sheet so I can add the 5 separate numbers for each team together to get a total